# Does the number of "days" that a save has been going on for, matter?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

Does the number of "days" that a save has been going on for, matter, in either the first game or the second? Or is it just for your information and has no effect on anything?

Because I've been sleeping and farming for loot in the Den of Devil in the first game for I forgot how long and am at 400+ days, and I want to know if I should reset.

Are there some timed quests that fail if not completed in some number of days, or only are available in certain day ranges? Or is the "days" count just something for those who want to know stats?

Sort of important, given that reloading the second game's tutorial quest advances the clock by 2 days, then autosaves.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one time based achievement on Steam.  That is intentionally somewhat vague soas not to spoiler anyone but should allow searching if folks want to know more.